# I get an error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'MISCELLANEOUS' to data type int " when I use group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    timecollected, SUM(waitingtaskscounttotal) waitingtaskscounttotal 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         timecollected, CAST(raw_value AS INT) AS waitingtaskscounttotal
     FROM 
         spotlight_perfdata sp
     JOIN 
         spotlight_stat_names sn ON sp.statistic_name_id = sn.statistic_name_id
                                 AND sn.statistic_class_id = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @statistic_class_id)
     WHERE 
         sp.statistic_class_id = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @statistic_class_id)
         AND (sp.timecollected >= convert(NVARCHAR, @firstdate, 126)
              AND sp.timecollected <= convert(NVARCHAR, @lastdate, 126))
         AND sp.monitored_object_id = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @monitored_object_id)
         AND sn.statistic_name = 'waitingtaskscounttotal') TableA
GROUP BY 
    timecollected
ORDER BY 
    timecollected DESC
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'MISCELLANEOUS' to data type int.

But after I removed the column `timecollected` from the SQL statement, it worked:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(waitingtaskscounttotal) waitingtaskscounttotal 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         timecollected, CAST(raw_value AS INT) AS waitingtaskscounttotal
     FROM 
         spotlight_perfdata sp
     JOIN 
         spotlight_stat_names sn ON sp.statistic_name_id = sn.statistic_name_id
                                 AND sn.statistic_class_id = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @statistic_class_id)
     WHERE 
         sp.statistic_class_id = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @statistic_class_id)
         AND (sp.timecollected >= convert(NVARCHAR, @firstdate, 126)
              AND sp.timecollected <= convert(NVARCHAR, @lastdate, 126))
         AND sp.monitored_object_id = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @monitored_object_id)
         AND sn.statistic_name = 'waitingtaskscounttotal') TableA
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: May be your data raw_value  would have value 'MISCELLANEOUS' and you are trying to convert this to int as **cast(raw_value AS INT)** so error displays.

Comment: yes, the column raw_value type is sql_variant, and it does have the value MISCELLANEOUS, but the Where clause would filter it out, the problem is why the second statement works

Comment: The problem is, the query optimizer can re-order how it evaluates the statement - there's no guarantee that a `where` clause filter will be applied before the attempted `int` conversion. This is why I'd always recommend against a design using variants and instead use multiple columns for the various types of values that may be stored (with appropriate check constraints to ensure that the correct columns are null/not null based on the expected type to be stored)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
CAST(raw_value AS INT)
```

to this:

```
CASE 
WHEN raw_value like '%[0-9]%' and not raw_value like '%[^0-9]%' 
OR raw_value like '-%[0-9]%' and not raw_value like '-%[^0-9]%' 
THEN CAST(raw_value AS int)
ELSE NULL
END
```

This will make everything which is not an int, `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the issue, I save the data filtered out by `where` clause to a temp table and then do the `int` conversion.